# Why do my buttons with tkinter not show text?

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm

I am trying to make my own gui with Python. I am using Tkinter and eventhough I made the buttons show text, the text won´t show up.

````
import classes

root = Tk()
root.geometry('395x400')
e = Entry(root, width=60, borderwidth=5)
e.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=10, pady=10)

#buttons

button_add_student=Button(root, name="add student",  padx=90, pady=20, command=)
button_show_student=Button(root, name="enter",  padx=90, pady=20, )
button_add_student.grid(row=1, column=0)
button_show_student.grid(row=1, column=1)
root.mainloop() ```
````

Comment: Did you mean: `text="add student"`?

Comment: @quamrana yep that´s what I meant

Answer (score 0):

They don't show text but you haven't given them any text to show. If you want a button to have a textual label then you need to provide a value to the `text` attribute:

```
button_add_student=Button(root, text="add student", ...)
button_show_student=Button(root, text="enter", ...)
```

You were using the `name` attribute, which specifies the internal name for the widget. The name is only visible if you print out the string representation of the widget (eg: `print(str(button_add_student))`).